# Can a function return a pointer to NULL?

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception

```
class sll_item
{private:
    sll_item *next_;
    int code_;
...
...

class sll_
{ private:
    sll_item *first_;
    sll_item *last_;
...
...

sll_item* sll_ :: lookforitem(int code)
{
  sll_item* aux = first_;
  while(code != aux->getcode() && aux != NULL){
    aux = aux->getnext();
  }
  return aux;
}
```

This function is looking for an item in a simple-linked list, but if the function doesn´t find it, the program crashes telling segment violation (I think this is the name in English).

I want to know if is found or not to tell the user a message of not found or something like this. Thanks.

Comment: yes, nullptr (not Null, NULL or null - those are old tricks and if you want programm in modern style use nullptr keyword) can be returned by fnc as indicator of "Not found"

Answer (score 8):

You may not have shown us all of the problem code, but this is an issue right here:

```
while(code != aux->getcode() && aux != NULL){
```

you're using the pointer "aux", and *then* testing whether it's NULL. That's not good; you need to do it the other way round:

```
while(aux != NULL && code != aux->getcode()){
```

If you have a pointer that might be null, you always need to check it *before* dereferencing it.

Comment: Maybe tell him about the && short-circuiting :)

Comment: Indeed, @freinn, maybe you know this already, but in an "&&" expression, the subexpressions are evaluated left to right, and if the first one is false, the second one is not evaluated at all.

Comment: I know the short-circuiting, but I saw more probable to find the code instead of get the end of the list. Thanks!

Comment: @freinn Dereferensing is when you access the object a pointer points to. In this case using "->".

Answer (score 2):

```
while(code != aux->getcode() && aux != NULL){
    aux = aux->getnext();
}
```

Yes, it will crash if `aux` is NULL, because you're trying to get code first by writing`aux->getcode()` and then check if `aux` is not NULL.  That is, `aux->getcode()` is executed before `aux != NULL`.

Now think, what if aux is NULL? `aux->getcode()` would crash!

The loop should be written as:

```
while(aux != NULL && code != aux->getcode()){
  aux = aux->getnext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use like this

```
while(aux != NULL&&code != aux->getcode())
```

Firstly, test that aux is not NULL, then you can use `atx->getcode()`.